# Woocommerce Germanized move terms and conditions checkboxes to before submit

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to move the checkboxes in WC checkout germanized from before the payment info to before the submit button.

I have successfully added another set of checkboxes before the submit button using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_render_pay_for_order_checkboxes', 10 );
```

Now I´ve got two sets of checkboxes, one above the payment info, and the one added by the above code.

I can´t figure out how to remove the first and initial set of checkboxes.
Maybe there is someone with a similar problem, who has figured out a solution.

I've tried

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_show_terms', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_render_pay_for_order_checkboxes', 10 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'woocommerce_gzd_before_legal_checkbox_direct-debit-checkbox', 10 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'woocommerce_checkout_before_terms_and_conditions', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, and your solution does (and doesn't do) the same things here. I have not found a real solution, but I can hide things with CSS:

```
div.wc-gzd-checkbox-placeholder:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

Maybe this works for you too. You might have to change the nth-child parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, on the WP support page for Germanized.
Put this in your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_child_move_legal_checkboxes', 50 );

function my_child_move_legal_checkboxes() {
    // Remove
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_payment', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_render_checkout_checkboxes', 10 );
    // Right before submit button
    add_action( 'woocommerce_gzd_review_order_before_submit', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_render_checkout_checkboxes', 10 );
}
```

Please ignore my former answer.
I will leave it here, maybe it can help with similar problems.